# How to use package specific typescript paths in a typescript monorepo?

Tags: typescript, tsc

Lets say the following folder structure is present. The frontend directly imports a type from the backend (via workspace:) to use tRPC. The backend does not transpile into javascript, rather is directly imported in the frontend. This is done because you want to have the routes type updated live in both the frontend and the backend.

```
ui
    frontend
        src
            utils
            pages
        tsconfig.json
        package.json
        vite.config.js

services
    backend
        src
            utils
            routes
        package.json
        tsconfig.json
```

To keep paths clean, typescript `paths` are used in both the frontend and in the backend.

Ex. in the frontend, the following property is used in the backend `compilerOptions`:

```
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"]
    }
```

Everything works just using vite without running tsc. But if type checking is wanted (running tsc && vite in the frontend directory), it just outputs `../../services/backend/src/x Cannot find module '@utils/x' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Supposedly this is because it uses the tsconfig in the folder where tsc is ran from, which in this case is frontend. What is needed is to make it use the tsconfig.json present in the backend for typechecking there?